# Why the clearTimeout cannot cancel the setTimeout in while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, settimeout

In my opinion , the`clearTimeout(timer)` will be executed first, and why it can not kill the `timer`, the browser will still alert .

The code is here:

```
var  i = 0, timer , j =0
              while(i++ <2){
                    timer = window.setTimeout(
                                       function(){
                                           j++;alert(j)
                                           }, 1000)
              };
               clearTimeout(timer)
```

Comment: There is *one* `timer` variable; yet the loop runs two times, adding multiple timers, before any is cleared. How can *one* variable (containing a singular opaque id) clear *both* timeouts?

Comment: @user2864740  I got it ，thx.

Comment: Your code creates 2 timers and clearTimeout kills the last one.
In the second loop the handler to the first setTimeout get lost.